# Did Agent Coulson die in The Avengers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, marvel, the-avengers-2012

Given the upcoming *Agents of Shield* TV show, there has been some desire for a return of [Agent Coulson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phil_Coulson).  Is there evidence that he canonically died in *The Avengers* or evidence that this is another one of Nick Fury's manipulations?

Comment: I suspect his claimed death was greatly exagerated, just like the bloody Captain America trading cards, and just more of Fury's manipulation to get the Avengers to coalesce. The Son-of-Coul is hard to kill. He'll be back after a heart transplant and a nasty scar to remind him not to mix it up mano-a-mano with 'real power'.

Comment: I have heard rumors that Coulson might also return in the *Avengers* sequel.

Comment: Note that *Avengers* contains a throwaway reference to Life Model Decoys...

Comment: It's not as if death has evern been that great a barrier for returning in regular Comic Books, hard to believe they'd make an exception for the film/tv universe.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Yes. Coulson died.

Joss answered this at the 2014 SXSW. From [this article](http://www.cinemablend.com/television/Joss-Whedon-Tells-SXSW-Crowd-How-He-Bring-Coulson-Back-From-Dead-53483.html) (emphasis mine):

> Acknowledging the presence of seemingly-deceased Agent Coulson (Clark Gregg) on the panel – Gregg plays Leonato in the Much Ado ensemble – Whedon tried to explain how the S.H.I.E.L.D. agent returns from the dead.
>
> “I’ll tell you guys this, Heimlich,” Whedon joked, before effectively clamming up about the show. “I can’t talk about it,” he admitted, but said that **he did bring Coulson back from the dead for the ABC drama. “Yes. For realsies.”**

#### Within the TV show

Agent Hill says that Coulson died for 8 seconds (though he claims 40) and that Fury faked a full death to unite the Avengers. Coulson was sent to recover in Tahiti.

However...

> A short exchange between Agent Hill and <del>Shepherd Book</del> Dr. Streiten leads viewers to believe that there is still more to Coulson's "death" and "recovery" than Coulson or the viewer knows.

In Season 1, Episode 3: (The Asset)

> A major point is made to demonstrate that Coulson has lost what should have been instinctive muscle memory when he is unable to take apart and reassemble a gun as quick as he normally could pre-impalement.

In Season 1, Episode 11: (A Magical Place)

> Dr. Streitan explains that Coulson had been dead for days and that his memories had been altered. After being revived (by some still unknown means), his memories are altered to restore him to something closer to his original pre-death personality.

#### Within the movies

It's worth noting that while Coulson has been revived, and is alive and kicking in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, Whedon still considers him dead for the purposes of the movies, explaining [why he hasn't shown up in any of the MCU movies since his trip to TAHITI](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/86951/5184).

[Whedon explained](http://mentalfloss.com/uk/movies/28527/qa-joss-whedon-on-super-heroes-the-pop-culture-mainstream).

> A lot of people come back in The Winter Soldier. It’s a grand Marvel tradition. Bucky was supposed to die. And the Coulson thing was, I think, a little anomalous just because that really came from the television division, which is sort of considered to be its own subsection of the Marvel universe. **As far as the fiction of the movies, Coulson is dead.**

However, since Whedon has stepped back from his position as one of the primary forces in the MCU creative team, The Powers That Be™ may change this.

Comment: Well then.  *Awesome.*

Comment: He brought something back. ZOMBIE COULSON

Comment: I think life-model decoy is currently the leading theory, though without much direct evidence. I assume we'll find out over the course of the show.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield One piece of minor evidence has shown up since you posted that comment

Comment: *Almost Human* crossover. I'm calling it.

Comment: At the end of episode 7, “The Hub”, Coulson tries to get his recovery report from Tahiti, and is told that he doesn’t have clearance to access those files.

Comment: @alexwlchan Yes, but that doesn't really reveal any new details regarding his fate.

Comment: @phantom42: no, but it’s an extra detail that emphasises that something is up that Coulson doesn’t know. I thought it was worth adding to the post.

Comment: Given that the episode has aired this question should be closed because we know the definitive answer...

Comment: @DoctorWho22 Wha? We don't close questions because they have a definitive answer.

Comment: @phantom42 Well not sure how to put spoilers but whatever.. They stated he wasn't dead for a few seconds... or hours.. he was dead for days... He was kind of being kept alive artificially, aka his brain... While they operated on him to save his life... This is why he lost some of his motor skills and feels different..  So in short yes he literally died.. What we don't now is the extent of how they saved his life through what operations and such.

Answer (score -2):

Actually in the marvels agents of shield tv show coulson is revived by Fury using alien blood. Coulson belived he died for 40 seconds but nick revealed it was over a week. So Coulson didn’t accept that he was put through all of that pain just to come back to life and he just wanted to die. He also started writing alien symbols on to the wall which is later revealed to be a city

Comment: While this answer is correct in most ways, it could use some better formatting as well possibly adding in relevant quotes and episode numbers to help support your answer.