# In comics, does S.H.I.E.L.D. have tech to revive dead?

Tags: marvel, shield

In *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* TV series, Dr. Streitan told Coulson that Coulson was dead for days after Loki stabbed him. So, certainly, S.H.I.E.L.D. has tech to revive deads.

The TV series hasn't featured this tech yet, but upcoming episode may reveal it as Skye's life is in danger.

I am unable to wait till the episode broadcast. So, I want to know if S.H.I.E.L.D. has such tech in a canon other than Earth-19999. If yes, what is it? How does it work?

Comment: I don't know if it ever really comes up, since every time Nick Fury dies ... it's a Life Model Decoy.  Which is why a lot of people assumed Coulson was as well.

Comment: @joshbirk Ha.. Ha.. I don't think it was Coulson's LMD which died. [Real Coulson really died](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/33871/931).

Comment: Right right, more specifically people assumed new Coulson was an LMD.  In the comics, SHIELD seems to go through those like candy.

Comment: Honestly, I love this show, but can't you just wait for the story to unfold? It's still in its first season; obviously there are some questions on the program which have not been answered yet. This one is at least comic-related, but it's spoiler-ish - bear in mind, not all countries have *SHIELD* airing at the same time - and related to a TV show in progress. Your comment to joshbirk was even more spoiler-tastic.

Comment: While it hasn't brought anyone back from the dead, Nicky Fury regularly ingests the Infinity Formula, which has prolonged his life and kept him in his current vital state for decades. But like I said, it hasn't brought anyone back from the dead so I'm leaving it as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Not really.

In the 616 Universe, no technologically-based mortal species has the capacity to restore life to the deceased.  There are magical means to reanimate the dead, supernatural entities who can pierce death's door, alien races who can defeat injury beyond human science, and some terrestrial organizations which can create various forms of cyborgs, but no surgical means of resurrection.

Things are even worse over in [Earth-1610](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Marvel), which has enforced a "dead is dead" rule for quite some time.

---

Mind you, SHIELD's competence is highly variable, and given sufficient need some persons within the organization might be able to finagle a magical ressurection or a time-travel based in-universe retcon.

Answer (score 3):

Please note the existance of Deathlok in the Marvel universe which appears to be hinted at in Agents of SHIELD.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathlok The term refers to a series of dead individuals reanimated with advanced tech.  This is clearly reanimation, however, and not resurrection.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question directly. None that have been shown to date. We do know that they have access to technology from other worlds. We have seen other races can revive the dead... However they do not have any outright technology which they use standard or even in rare events thus far to show it. However they COULD get access to revive the dead through the various ways the dead rise in the Marvel Universe, I.E the spell used by the HAND. But no technology oh hand. Also this is not including cloning and placing mind in clone body.