# Why is Agent Coulson so important to Director Fury?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In an episode of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* TV series, Agent Victoria Hand said to Agent Ward that no agent was that important to the system (At the time, Agent Coulson had been kidnapped and his team was trying hard to find him).

However, during the events of the *Avengers* movie,

> Agent Coulson was impaled and [killed by Loki](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/33871/931). We later learn in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. that Director Fury had him revived via a classified project.

Why was Agent Coulson so important to Director Fury? He was just another Level 8 agent.

Comment: Their love is a forbidden love.

Comment: Coulson has a reputation within SHIELD, and commands a lot of respect from other high-ranking agents. That alone probably wouldn’t save him, but I don’t think he’s “just another Level 8 agent”.

Comment: @alexwlchan If that's the case, why did Victoria Hand argued Agent Ward about it?

Comment: @JamesSheridan Surely we'd be better off editing the question to make it clear that only answers with the canonical reason(s) are acceptable. Worst case is that the question sits unanswered for a while, I don't think it's right to close it just because there isn't currently an answer available.

Comment: @JamesSheridan "We don't know" is a perfectly valid canon answer.  Answers can be edited as things change.

Comment: @Keen: Good point. I've given that answer myself on other occasions, so I'm not sure why it didn't occur to me here.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 Victoria Hand is a level 8 agent like Coulson, so she wouldn't necessarily know any more than Coulson.

Comment: AFAIK the only Level-9 is Hill and Level-10 is Fury (and presumably Pierce). There's more analysis [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/55551/13024).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Per the season 1 finale, we have an answer.

> Coulson is one of the few people Nick Fury trusts.

In addition, he was crucial in the formation of The Avengers, which (per S1E20)

> T.A.H.I.T.I. was meant to resurrect, so using it to revive Coulson wasn't entirely outside the purview of T.A.H.I.T.I.

Then, per S1E18?

> Fury set May up to be Coulson's monitor, in case he started showing some of the side-effects of procedures.

Comment: Spoilerification please?

Comment: @Izkata I think all these spoilers are properly tagged with relevant episode numbers.