# Supernatural Season 9 - Is this character a Knight of Hell?

Tags: supernatural

There are ***HUGE*** spoilers in this question, and if you haven't watched the final episode of supernatural Season 9,  stop reading right **now**.

Okay, here's the question:

> In the final episode after Dean's "death", we see that he has came back as a Demon, or so it appears, since he now has the trademark black demon-eyes.
> But what is making me curious is what Crowley said. According to him, Cain himself tried to escape the effects of the Mark by killing himself with the Blade. But as we know, Cain wasn't a Demon,but he was a ***Knight of Hell***. Is it safe to assume that, much like Cain, the Mark turned Dean into a ***Knight of Hell***?

Comment: We probably won't know until next season, as (if I understand it correctly) it happened in the last few seconds of the finale.

Comment: @NikolaiDante: “We don’t know yet” can be a valid answer; e.g. see the comments on [this question about Agents of SHIELD](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50598/why-is-agent-coulson-so-important-to-director-fury)

Comment: Well I guess that once the next Season comes out I'll give it an awnser myself xP

Thanks for the replies though. And @NikolaiDante, yes it were on the very last few momments

Answer (score 3):

Per Dean's recapping of their recent adventures in the episode *Fan Fiction*, yes. Dean was turned not into a regular demon, but a full Knight of Hell.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm thinking something new is happening, but we won't learn exactly what until next season.

Things we know from prior episodes:

- Demons are human souls that were twisted in Hell and essentially put on overdrive.
- Cain was only the first of the Knights of Hell, it was an entire order.  They couldn't all have had the Mark ([and the Supernatural Wikia claims that all the Order were created by Lucifer directly and only trained by Cain, although I'm not sure of the reference](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Knight_of_Hell#Characteristics))

And from this episode:

> Mentioned by Crowley, Cain was strong enough to control the Mark, since it was made for him.  Dean was changing like that because he could not.

Comment: Crowley said that, among other things: "Apparently he too was willing to accept death rather than becoming the killer the Mark wanted him to be. So he took his own life with the Blade. He died. Except as rumor has it, the Mark never quite let go. " Which is why I think the Mark itself turned him into a Knight [Remember, the Mark WAS created by Lucifer]

Answer (score -1):

my answer would be yes he is now an immortal knight of hell because of the mark of Cain which will never let him die,not even an angel "blade" can kill him.But since he is now a demon he is now strong enough to withstand its urge to kill...just so you know no demon is stronger than dean now thus he can kick Crowley's ass and and unsit him from his throne of hell

Comment: Actually, Cain himself couldn't resist the urges to kill