# Do the Avengers know that Nick Fury isn't the Director?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron, agents-of-shield, nick-fury

Nick Fury made Phil Coulson the Director of S.H.I.E.L.D.

However,

> the Avengers don't know that Coulson is still alive

- but do they know that Nick Fury isn't the director anymore?

He brought the Helicarrier to the battle field in Sokovia with Maria Hill too, does it mean he's back in S.H.I.E.L.D? Or was he just trying to help as himself, but not as the director or working for S.H.I.E.L.D?

Comment: That Coulson is still alive isn't a spoiler, it was in all the marketing leading up to S1 of *AoS*.  *How* he's still alive is a spoiler, as it's a key plot arc in S1 of *AoS*.

Comment: @keen saying that he is still alive implies that he died in the first place, which is a spoiler for Avengers.

Comment: I don't think we need to worry about Avengers spoilers on this site in 2015. Also, the first episode of AoS aired after Avengers and the commercials had the "spoiler".

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I wasn't the one who hid it. I'm just explaining what I presumed the reason to be.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86948/why-arent-mcu-movies-featuring-coulson-after-avengers)

Comment: I think that you could consider the Avengers initiative a program created by shield, but not otherwise attached to it.  The Avengers and Shield can be considered separate entities now, and, for a variety of out of universe reasons, the movies and TV shows are related, but are intended to be separate enough that you can enjoy one without seeing the other, which limits the amount of interaction.

Comment: There's probably an incredible *Age of Ultron* cut-scene floating around where Cap pins Fury against the barn wall, veins nearly bursting from his forehead, and yells _“SHOW ME AN ORG CHART NICK!!! HOW CAN I FIGHT WITHOUT KNOWING WHERE TO SEND MY WEEKLY PROGRESS REPORT?!?!?”_

Answer (score 19):

Early in the conversation between Tony and Nick in the barn, there's this exchange:

> **Tony-** You're not the director of me.
>
> **Nick-** I'm not the director of anybody.

So yes, the Avengers know that Nick Fury is no longer the Director of S.H.I.E.L.D.  That he still has access to S.H.I.E.L.D. gear and (former) agents should surprise no one given how resourceful he is.  That TV viewers know that S.H.I.E.L.D. is still active and run by Coulson is a nice Easter Egg.

Answer (score -2):

Phil Coulson is the director in the TV version of the MCU.

In the movie version, Nick Fury is director.

Jos Whedon has said in interviews that Phil Coulson is still dead in the movies:

> "Yeah he’s dead. The entire television series is just a fever dream. As far as I’m concerned in the films, yes he’s dead."

Comment: Uhhhh... wot?  Did a director just invoke head-canon?

Comment: @Radhil more of saying Marvel Studio's policy. That the movie universe doesn't acknowledge the tv universe.

Comment: I guess that's fine as a policy, especially to stave off continuity hell and avoid movies that are wall-to-wall references.  It's another thing entirely to say it don't exist. Maybe he's just picking on Jed, I dunno.

Comment: Sentences like `X is still dead` make me want to ask "Please notify me if there is a change in his state"... :-p

Comment: @SJuan76 it actually happened a lot in the MCU!

Comment: Do you have a source for what you put in the last spoiler section?

Comment: @Justin an IGN interview.

Comment: @JustinC see my answer on [Why aren't MCU movies featuring Coulson after Avengers?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/86951/5184)

Comment: Perspective is important.  Only current Shield agents know that Coulson is still alive.  Yes, they may have heard rumors, but Coulson's death was well publicized.  This means that, while it is known that Nick Fury is not the director, it is not public knowledge who is the director.

Comment: @SJuan76 You mean "*when* there is a change...".

Comment: @Trisped Considereding what Ward says in the Pilot, *"I'm clearance Level Six. I know that... Agent Coulson was killed in action before the battle of New York."*, it would appear that it wasn't *that* publicized.

Comment: @ibid Right, so I should have said "... but Coulson's death was well publicized to SHIELD and The Avengers."

Comment: There is no TV version of the MCU and film version of the MCU, there are simply films and TV shows set within the MCU. Joss Whedon is not in charge of the canonicity of MCU properties, and if the quote in question comes from the place I think it does, he was talking about Coulson being dead to **the characters** in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, not in **the universe** - i.e. it's important to his characters they they still believe that Coulson is dead. See my answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/86999/24087) for a more in depth explanation.

Comment: @DrRDizzle The movies and tv shows, while officially set in the same universe, are run by different departments which often don't run together smoothly. Various people at Marvel have commented on this including Kevin Feige. The quote from Joss was about why he wasn't planning to put Coulson in the AoU. I'm aware that he doesn't control the rest of the MCU and was invoking his own personal headcanon. The fact remains, however, that the main reason why Coulson won't appear in the movies is the movies don't acknowledge events from the TV shows. As far as the movies are concerned, he's still dead.

Comment: @ibid The movies haven't **directly** referenced the TV shows so far, but the fact is that the location of Baron von Struckers base in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* is only known to The Avengers thanks to Coulson, who told Maria Hill about it. Additionally, the Helicarrier Fury turns up on in Sokovia is given to him by Coulson, who was keeping it for an emergency under the name Theta Protocol. As far **some of the characters in the movies** are concerned, he's dead - but he is canonically alive within the movies themselves, and the universe they take place in.

Comment: @DrRDizzle the impression that I got from  was that AoU didn't explain those things because it was completely unnecessary to and would have just detracted from the movie. AoS as usual tried finding random gaps to insert itself. As of now, all *internal evidence* from the movies shows that they're not connected to the shows.

Comment: @ibid There is no internal evidence in the text of the films that contradicts the existence of the TV shows. And a lack of evidence that the shows do exist from the films side of things doesn't mean that they don't exist - the absence of evidence is not the evidence of absence.

Comment: @DrRDizzle nothing that directly contradicts, but stuff that come across as strange. (e.g. all of shield's operations in AoS involve the same eight guys, but then the massive shield helicarrier in AoU is staffed with completely different guys.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33315/discussion-between-dr-r-dizzle-and-ibid).