# What is Agent Coulson's status as of the end of Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

This certainly may seem like a duplicate of

[Why aren't MCU movies featuring Coulson after Avengers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86948/why-arent-mcu-movies-featuring-coulson-after-avengers)

However that question is more general and all the answers are from the *Avengers: Age of Ultron* timeframe and are focused on the idea of 'appearance in film'

I haven't watched *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, but it seems like, given the all encompassing cast of *Endgame*, that at least a cameo or an appearance at

> Tony Stark's funeral

would be in order.   Unless there's a simple in-universe explanation.

**What is Agent Coulson's status as of the end of Endgame?**

This does not necessarily have to do with whether he appears on-screen.   It is just that the events of *Endgame* make his absence all the more conspicuous.

Comment: To be honest still sounds like a duplicate to me so voting to close. As far as I know not many, if any, of the MCU TV characters cameo in Endgame aside from Edwin Jarvis I suppose.

Comment: @ThePopMachine, it's possible it was because of actor contracts too. Could be Disney/Marvel couldn't sign on Clark Gregg because he was busy shooting seasons of AoS. Just depends on outside forces at work. I don't think there is any in-universe explanation. Not unless they reveal it in season 6. Remember that ABC and Disney/Marvel have to work very hard at season sync-ups with film events. Could be, that maybe cameoing Coulson in IW or Endgame would have caused a can of worms explosion for that carefully balanced synchronization.

Comment: May I draw everyone's attention to [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12505/how-do-we-resolve-this-supposed-dupe-situation) meta.

Comment: Following the discussion and voting on [the meta about this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12505/31394), consensus is that it's **not a duplicate**, so I've reopened it. Comments here about its dupe status have also been removed; please take any further such discussion to the meta post and not here.

Comment: He's ***THRIVING***

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:   Is that a reference I don't get?

Comment: Could be! Lemme [refresh ya](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/195710/440).

Answer (score 7):

The events of season 5 of *Agents of SHIELD* prevent Coulson from taking part in anything that happens during *Endgame*.

> TL;DR: Coulson is (finally! again!) dead in the MCU, before *Endgame* takes place. He was also no longer SHIELD Director by this point, and SHIELD is effectively (again!) defunct, so wouldn't be much use in the battle.

An important subplot of season 5, particularly the latter half, is that Coulson

> is dying, and in order to prevent the future the team travelled to, they may need to let him die.

In the final episode of the season, *The End*, Simmons gives Coulson some of the Centipede serum, which was established early in the series as a (flawed) super-soldier type drug. For Coulson, this is

> a cure (although possibly temporary), but

he hides it and gives it to Daisy (Skye).

> (Daisy needs it for the super-strength, not as a cure).

At the very end of the episode, we see Coulson and May in Tahiti,

> where Coulson is content to spend his last days in peace. It is established that he has only a very short time left.

Season 6 of *SHIELD* has Clark Gregg playing a different (as far as we currently know) character, Sarge, who happens to look exactly like Coulson. It's not clear yet, but presumably Sarge has no reason to fight in the *Endgame* battle, or to

> attend Tony's funeral.

Given that both Season 5 and *Endgame* are time-travel stories, it's tricky to place everything, but episode 20 takes place at the same time as *Infinity War*, as there's an explicit comment that Thanos is attacking the Earth right then. Episodes 21 and 22 follow on directly from episode 20, and are before the

> first

'snap', and certainly well before the latter events of *Endgame*.

(I haven't seen Season 6 yet, but I understand it's set a year after Season 5, which should put it between *Infinity War* and *Endgame*, but I understand that because of scheduling uncertainty they couldn't reference anything that happens in *Endgame*, so I'm unclear how the 'snaps' link into the show. However, I don't think that impacts Coulson's status).

Comment: I hope you'll keep updating this as things progress.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I'll try. AoS 6 isn't available in NZ (except maybe Xbox, haven't checked there) so keeping up to date is challenging.

Comment: " Episodes 21 and 22 follow on directly from episode 20, and are before the [spoiler] 'snap'," I don't think that saying "Thanos' snap" would be a spoiler for Endgame.

Comment: With S6 (and S7) completed, you can updated this now. It's clear AoS doesn't happen in the same universe as Endgame.

Answer (score 1):

### We don't currently know (as of the beginning of Season 6), as *Agents of SHIELD* is now running 4 years behind the MCU Prime-timeline.

Signs point to "[still dead in the MCU movie-verse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/86951/5184)".

---

While the end of Season 5 of *Agents of SHIELD* coincided with the events of *Infinity War*, it also featured the retirement and impending death of Coulson. Season 6 picks up one year later, with Agent Melinda May saying that Coulson died between seasons - not a casualty of the Snap.

While actor Clark Gregg is still active on the show, it is as a new, separate character named Sarge. To date, there has been no indication that Coulson will be revived.

---

*Avengers Endgame* jumps 5 years ahead, and did feature the un-snapping of many characters, but only characters who had been snapped out of existence were restored. Since Coulson was dead the last we heard, was not restored by the un-snap, and was not at the funeral, it stands to reason that he is still dead.

---

n.b.: [Agents of SHIELD season 6 deliberately avoided crossing over with Avengers Endgame](https://www.thewrap.com/agents-of-shield-season-6-avengers-endgame-marvel/)

Comment: It turns out The Snap never happened in AoS. The Universes have completely diverged.